# Decide which activity to start from a subclass of Application

Tags: java, android

I have a simple application in which before I do anything, I must check whether the user is logged in or not.
To do this, I inherited the `Application` class like this:

```
public class GBApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (userIsLoggedIn()) {
            Intent overviewActivity = new Intent(this, Overview.class);
            overviewActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(overviewActivity);
        }
    }    
}
```

`userIsLoggedIn()` returns a boolean stored in the `SharedPreferences` file.

Everything works, but when I press back from the `Overview` activity, it redirects me to the default activity (`MainActivity`), and removing it from the `AndroidManifest.xml` files gives error.
Also, I can't call `finish()` since this is a non activity class.

How can I terminate my program after I return from the `Overview` class? I found solutions where they pass a value to the `MainActivity`, call `finish()` from there. But this seems to complicated.
What else I can do?

This is my [`application`](https://pastebin.com/wdL2e9Mr) tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Why not just override the onBackPressed() of your overviewActivity?

Comment: This is extraordinarily bad. Every time your process is created, you are starting an activity, even if an activity is not needed for this particular process. Have `MainActivity` handle both scenarios (e.g., using fragments for distinct UI for each case). Or, have `MainActivity` decide to start `Overview` if needed.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'll follow your advice and create a Dummy activity that will have the only role to judge what to start.
But could you expand your answer and tell me more about what is it bad? Shouldn't be easier since we are not starting an intermediary activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plan is going to cause problems. Every time your process is created, you are starting an activity, even if an activity is not needed for this particular process.

Displaying a launcher activity — such as in response to the user tapping on a home screen launcher icon — is *one* way that a process might be created for your app. But there are many others:

- `AlarmManager`
- `JobScheduler`
- a `Notification`
- a push message (e.g., from Firebase Cloud Messaging)
- a request sent to a `ContentProvider` that you export from your app
- a request sent to a `Service` that you export from your app
- a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`
- the user returning to your task in the overview screen
- and so on

In none of those scenarios is displaying this activity necessarily appropriate. Yet, your code will display the activity in all of them, because any time Android forks a process for your app, you display this activity.

Have all of your activities (other than the login one) see if the user is logged in, and route the user to the login activity if that is needed. When the user completes the login, and the login activity finishes, the user is returned to where they were trying to go, whether that is your launcher activity or some other activity (e.g., they returned to your task after your app had been in the background for a while, so your process was terminated, but Android tries to send them back to whatever activity of yours they had been in last).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply override the onBackPressed() of your overviewActivity and pilot the direction your app goes when the back button is pressed (*which in your case is to shut down the app*):

```
@Override
   public void onBackPressed(){
      startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
}
```

The code above just shuts down your app immediately the back button is clicked once (which is pretty boring.. but simple). You could also try the code snippet below; it pops up a dialogue box:

```
    @Override
   public void onBackPressed(){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
}
```